# Using the indefinite article or zero article with "20/20 vision" when referring to sight measurements

Tags: indefinite-articles, historical-change

While looking at [the search results for "a 20/20 vision"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+20%2F20+vision%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbas=0&biw=1535&bih=1280&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1980&tbm=bks) in [a question on ELL asking whether there should be an article before 20/20 vision](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/274834/9161), I noticed that many of the results that were the correct context and from sources that were not obviously written by non-native speakers seemed to be grouped between the 1920s and 1960s. For example,

> In that state you must have **a** 20 / 20 vision in one eye , or **a** 20 / 30 vision in the better eye and at least 20 / 40 vision in the poorer eye ([Source from 1935](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Year_Book_of_the_Eye_Ear_Nose_and_Th/gEdEAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0))

[image: Image of text transcribed below]

> Don't let **a 20/20 vision** lull you into a false sense of eye security. It's a common misconception, say University of Chicago eye specialists, that a 20/20 finding means normal vision. ([Source from 1955](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_Digest/pr0PAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0))

I attempted to use Google's NGram viewer to get a better look, but I struggled with getting it to recognize the syntax to handle the "/" properly and couldn't get it to return meaningful results showing the contexts where the phrase was detected. The examples I could find often freely mixed using the indefinite article and the zero article in the same sentence, and looking at the image of the text, it wasn't an OCR error.

[image: Image of text transcribed below]

> **With a 20/20 vision in each eye**, the stop sign as well as the word "STOP" could be seen distinctly at 255 ft., both eyes open. **With 20/30 vision in each eye** it was visible at 200 ft. With 20/70 vision it was visible at 100ft...

Prior to looking at the examples, I thought that an article shouldn't be used vision measurements like "20/x vision". Now, I'm not so sure.

Is it acceptable to use either the indefinite article or zero article with a vision measurement in modern AmE, for example, "The pilot had a 20/20 vision in both eyes." If not, did it used to be acceptable and the usage evolved away from using an article? Is there a difference in BrE?

Because of my difficulties searching the corpora available to me, I feel like I may be interpreting a few spurious results as more important than they are, but I'd like to know one way or the other.

Comment: Honestly, I think the example you give is just an error. "20/20" has the effect of an adjective, and it is just as incorrect to saw "with a good vision in each eye" as it is to say "with a 20/20 vision in each eye." So your view that the indefinite article is not needed is correct, despite the counter example you found. At best I'd say the article was using a figure of speech, where "20/20 vision" meant "excellent visual capability". So "With an excellent visual capability in each eye." This does seem to be what the author means, but it is certainly a jarring phrase to my native ear.

Comment: @FraserOrr That is only one example of multiple instances I found in the time period I mentioned. I don't think there are a lot of instances out there, but I'm not sure because I don't have the tools to do a proper search. I'm a native speaker, and it sounds odd to me too. I would never recommend that a learner use the article, but I wonder if at some point in the past it was acceptable to use it either way. I don't want to get too hung up on the one example I picked from the multiples I found.

Comment: You could check using a Google search for the expanded versions: "with [a] twenty-twenty vision". The anarthrous version is far more idiomatic (notice that there are quite a few false positives such as 'Kick off the year with a Twenty-Twenty Vision Workshop', and arguably lyrics).

Comment: FWIW @EdwinAshworth I think the "a" in "a twenty-twenty vision workshop" applies to "workshop" not "vision". Here "twenty-twenty vision" is an appositive so functions effectively as an adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I still get no results in the Ngram viewer... I've tried "20-20" as well and it sort of seems to work if I don't try to mark it with `[ ]` to explicitly indicate I don't want `/` or `-` interpreted as an operator. I just don't trust that I'm getting accurate results with this particular phrase and Google.

Comment: “20/20 vision” without article appears to be more commonly used https://www.google.com/search?q=a+20/20+vidion&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&oq=a+20/20+vidion&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i8i13i30j0i390.5984j0j7&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&pccc=1

Comment: @user66974 That's my feeling, but I don't think looking at the first page of 69 million results is useful at figuring out if it used to be OK to use the article with it.

Comment: How else can this be tackled? There _are_ linguists who have majored on the usages of the articles, including Master, and Collins Cobuild have written a 100+ -page monograph on the subject, but I doubt you'll see this particular example addressed. // Google ngrams quite probably omit optical periodicals from their surveys. Most hits on a Google search might be expected to be from reasonably articulate sources, or readily discountable.

Comment: @Fraser Orr 'false positives'???

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would really like to find a way to do an ngram search so we can see the distribution over time.

Comment: @ColleenV: It's easier to use Google Books rather than NGrams for this kind of corpus search. I just searched for ["she has 20-20 vision"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+has+20-20+vision%22), where I switched to "Sorted by **Date**" because I think it forces greater accuracy. I was able to scroll through 5 pages or results (10 written instances per page = **50** examples). But when I searched for ["she has **a** 20-20 vision"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+has+a+20-20+vision%22) I got precisely ***one*** matching example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, but I think that's because of the punctuation... The search that spawned this question had a lot of results, but when I try to drill down, I get all sorts of inconsistencies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What are the sources of  the "twenty-twenty" results? I'm not seeing any books listed for it. It's interpreting the "-" as a subtraction. I'm trying to explain that it's really difficult to trust the Google search results for this particular phrase. I have quite a bit of expertise in formulating searches (I've been trained actually).

Comment: @ColleenV:  What? Are you seriously suggesting that perhaps ***a** 20-20 vision* is in fact far more common than my "fifty to one" result would imply? To be honest, I think it's actually ***less*** common than that - it's just that with such small numbers, ***one highly suspect example*** can disproportionately skew things.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not suggesting that in modern layperson's English it's common, and not hinging my entire question on one example I dredged out of Google books.

Comment: The reason I included ***she*** in my GB search was simply to limit the numbers so I could get "comparable" values. If I take that out and search for "has **a** 20-20 vision" I do actually get a total of 17 hits (maybe half-a-dozen after stripping out accidental collocations and duplicates). But that needs to be set against hundreds if not thousands of hits for the article-less version, and I know from prior experience that GB will stop delivering me results long before it actually runs out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am fully confident that today the "correct" answer is to not use the article. When I was looking through the search that was linked in the ELL question though, there was a cluster of books using the article prior to 1970 or so and it made me wonder if the usage evolved or if those were just mistakes or old-fashioned technical language. I've updated my question to include the search that made me curious.

Comment: That seems unlikely, given that (whether in digits or in words), [**twenty-twenty / 20-20 vision**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twenty-twenty+vision%2C20-20+vision&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwenty%20-%20twenty%20vision%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C20-20%20vision%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctwenty%20-%20twenty%20vision%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C20-20%20vision%3B%2Cc0) wasn't a common collocation until after WW2.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If that's accurate, why does that NGram not return any of the sources for its chart? I don't know that it is detecting what we think its detecting.

Comment: Apologies; one needs four 'wordsworths' apparently for << twenty-twenty >> on Google ngrams, which is prohibitive. One is stuck with raw Google searches, Google Books, and other corpora, possibly examining individual results.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's what I was afraid of - as a dabbler, I can't easily make use of other corpora so when Google fails me I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Google hasn't failed you. It's 98+% probable that 'Don't let a 20/20 vision lull you into a false sense of eye security.' is unusual, quirky, used here for effect (note that the article now goes anarthrous) and/or to highlight a specific (YOU may have 20/20 vision!) but would normally be considered unusual, quirky, borderline acceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How about "...Therefore, a 20/20 vision as recorded by one may be a 20/30 vision by another .." or "You were able to obtain a 20/20 vision in the uninjured eye?" or "The last time he had examined her there was a 20/20 vision"? Google has failed me because I can't get an answer that doesn't involve hand waving and saying "it's probably just quirky/bad writing/a mistake" etc.

Comment: @ColleenV: I think you're asking more of "the rules of English" than they can deliver. As Edwin says, any reference to 20/20 vision using an article would normally be considered unusual, quirky, borderline acceptable. There won't be any such thing as a "rule" saying *You should/can include the article in **this** context*, since we already know that the vast majority of native speakers don't know of any such rule, and hence couldn't recognise its "validity" anyway. And even if a handful of writers *did* agree on a rule, that would mean nothing to the rest of us.

Comment: I'd always rephrase here: 'What one optician records as 20/20 vision may well be judged to be 20/30 vision by another optician.' // Orwell trumps here: avoid what may be considered quirky, abrupt, unless you're aiming for that effect.